# Few records are created on my database table unconsciously

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Yeah our website has so many problems because we customized our website excessively. So a few of records on table were created/removed while I don't aware of it.

I tried to add `Time Stamp` column on some tables under this issue. But some fatal errors came out after adding `Time Stamp`. Because I just create column without setting on either foreign key or primary key.

This is one of the error messages I faced.

> An error occurred while saving this profile.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kbethos_wh`.`jet_profile_products`, CONSTRAINT `FK_JET_PROFILE_PRDS_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `jet_profile_products` (`profile_id`, `product_id`) VALUES (?, ?) File:/home/kbethos/public_html/wh/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php Line: 235

***My question is without any problem, I want to add time stamp column because I would like to know when they are created by whom or some codes I haven't noticed.***

I used this code to add time stamp column before

> ALTER TABLE `catalog_eav_attribute` ADD `lastUpdated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

Answer (score 0):

You just need to turn off Foreign key checks off before you run your query and then re-enable after

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

ALTER TABLE catalog_eav_attribute ADD lastUpdated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```